# adjust Mouse pointer speed using visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to make an application in visual studio 2010 (vb.net) that can adjust mouse pointer speed using a trackbar. I need help.

```
Public Sub getSpeedval()

Dim NewKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("ControlPanel\Mouse", True)
Dim GetVal As String = CType(NewKey.GetValue("MouseSpeed"), String)

End Sub
```

Comment: How can you expect to achieve this if you have no idea? There is no way that someone can just give you a complete walkthrough for something like this?

Comment: sorry sir, just Beginner, but here's the code I've tried but it didn't work, just need help sir for my project.

Comment: OK, I see you are new to this site and do not know how things work here. What you need to do is to edit your question. When editing, add the code from the comment above (code in comments is hard to read, paste the code when editing question, then select the code and press Ctrl+K). Also, provide a more detailed description of what you want to achieve. Finally, name the programming languange you are using and add its tag to the question. More people will try to help you this way.

Comment: thanks for understanding sir, is that ok sir?

Comment: Yes, this is much better?

Answer (score -1):

I cannot implement the whole program for you, but I can help you with the code you have posted. This code deals with retrieving data from value `MouseSpeed` of key `HKCU\Control Panel\Mouse`. There are two issues with it, the first one is that the path to the key is incorrect. You need a space between "Control" and "Panel". The second issue is that `Sub` in VB is a function that does not return a value.
You need to create a `Function`. Here is how it should look:

```
Public Function getSpeedval()
    Dim NewKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\Mouse", True)
    Dim GetVal As String = NewKey.GetValue("MouseSpeed")

    Return GetVal
End Function
```

and then you can call it in `Main` function like this:

```
Dim mouseSpeed = getSpeedval()
MsgBox("The value is " & mouseSpeed)
```

You can use a `Sub` to create a function that will set a new mouse speed because it does not need to return a value:

```
Public Sub setSpeedval(newSpeed)
    Dim NewKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\Mouse", True)
    NewKey.SetValue("MouseSpeed", newSpeed)
End Sub
```

You can use this function in main like this:

```
setSpeedval("2")
```

Hope this will help you enough so you can complete your program. Good Luck!

EDIT:

Please not that you have to use values `MouseThreshold1` and `MouseThreshold2`, not just `MouseSpeed`.

Comment: i tried it sir, it gets and change the value but the pointer's speed doesn't change. what i want is when i set the value, the pointer's movement will also move slow when I set the value into 1 and fast in greater value. is that possible sir? thanks for the corrections sir. appreciated!

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer sir, I don't know why it goes -1, i clicked up vote but it doesn't change, there's a message "Thanks for the feedback! once you earned 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicity displayed post score."

Comment: @Jomar It probably does not work because you have to change values `MouseThreshold1` and `MouseThreshold2`. See this post for explanation: http://superuser.com/questions/469044/how-to-increase-mouse-sensitivity-beyond-limits-in-windows-regedit

Comment: @Jomar As far as the votes go, I know you didn't downvote. The person who downvoted my answer also downvoted your question. I know this because I upvoted your question so it had score of one and now it has score zero. Don't worry about not being able to upvote my answer yourself, you don't have enough reputation for that. But you can mark it as selected answer, if it was helpful of course. Best of luck with your application!

Comment: thanks a lot sir, I read and tried  the examples on the link you gave, but still it didn't work. I set mouseSpeed to 2, MouseThreshold1 to 0 and MouseThreshold2 to 0, as said in the example there it is the max but still there is no changes in mouse sensitivity.